# Saving MongoDB query result into different variables in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a query for MongoDB written in Java, and I am trying to save the different results to variables. For instance the value in "Item" is supposed to be saved to a String with the name ItemName. And the value in "Seller" gets saved to another variable. How would I go about doing this?

Here i have the query...

```
        // Database Name
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Marketplace");

    // Collection name
    MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("Sales");

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

And  the result from the query is...

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5e74ae1f1c410c6af0670d9b"}, "Item": "Soap", "Seller": "Antoine", "Size": "null", "Condition": "New", "BIN": "100", "BID": "50", "Link": "null"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For automated mapping, you can use for example [Spring Data MongoDB](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb).

[Morphia](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia) is another option.